# Getting redux-form library initialValue injected into <Field>

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am building an EDIT form where the end user can see the previous data submitted, change it and save it back to the database.

The issue is to display the previous data inside the input fields. The form has been built with redux-form ([here the library](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/examples/initializefromstate/)) which uses `<Field>` components.

At the moment, the process is the following:

Get DATA & Dispatch
This code sends the data already saved in the database to a reducer

```
  React.useEffect(() => {

    axios.get(`${API.BASE_URL}${API.VIEW_STORES}/${params.storesid}`)
    .then(({data}) => {
      dispatch(editStoreFields(data))
    })
  }, [dispatch, params.storesid])
```

Reducer

```
export default function (state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case EDIT_STORE_FIELDS:
      return {
        ...state,
        myStore: action.data,
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Now I take the code sent to the reducer, pass it via mapStateToProps

```
class UsersForm extends Component {

  render() {
    const {
      handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting, t, myStore
    } = this.props;

    if(myStore === undefined) {
      return false
    }

    return (
      <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form__form-group">
          <span className="form__form-group-label">MY BUSINESS</span>
          <div className="form__form-group-field">
            <Field
              name="businessname"
              component={renderField}
              type="text"
              >>>>> ISSUE IS HERE <===== I need to inject the value of myStore.businessname in here, but I can't figure that out.
            />
          </div>
        </div>


        <ButtonToolbar className="form__button-toolbar">
          <Button color="primary" type="submit">SAVE</Button>
        </ButtonToolbar>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    myStore: state.storeReducer.myStore
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'vertical_form_validation', // a unique identifier for this form
  validate,
  enableReinitialize : true
}, mapStateToProps)(transHook(UsersForm));
```

Redux store value:

```
storeReducer:
   myStore:
     _id(pin):"610d12a52afdd35d4f2456a1"
    businessname(pin):"qeqe"
```

MyStore value returned via mapState...

```
{
 _id:"610d12a52afdd35d4f2456a1"
 businessname:"qeqe"
}
```

So, as you can see the routing for passing the data from the API GET call to the props is absolutely fine but I can't find a way to pass the props to the `<Field>` and display it as text which can be changed by the user and resubmitted.

Any help is much appreciated. Please note that you need to know how redux-form library works in order to suggest a solution.

Thanks Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
I've found the solution.

1st:

```
<Field
   name="businessname"
   component={renderField}
   type="text"
/>
```

nothing is needed here. The function mapStateToProps with `initialValues` will automatically use the `name` of the fields and assign the correct value.

Here the main part:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  initialValues: state.storeReducer.myStore
})
```

`myStore` is already an object with all the keys which matches the fields' names. With this syntax automatically I have all the fields in the HTML populated with the correct data which can be changed and re-submitted.

At the top, just to keep all inline, call the `initialValues` props for the IF statement:

```
const {
      handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting, t, initialValues
    } = this.props;

    if(initialValues === undefined) {
      return false
    }
```

This is not necessary to fix the issue, but I want to make a note in case you guys are following this code.